# Are questions related to reception of FM radio waves on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask a question related to increasing the reception quality of my clock radio. Is it on-topic on Electrical Engineering ?

Answer (score 6):

I think it would be on topic if you are asking about circuit modifications and perhaps antenna design.  If you are asking about commercially available "booster" devices, then no.